# How can I update Huawei Honor 4C

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, device-firmware, huawei-u8860

I need  Android 6.0 Marshmallow Firmware B067 Huawei Honor 4C (CHM-U01)

For this device: Huawei HONOR 4C, Model number: CHM-U01, Build number: CHM-U01 V100R001C185B067, CPU: Octa-core 1.2GHz, RAM: 2.0GB, Internal storage: 8GB, Android version: 4.4.2, Kernel version: 3.10.49-g3a7cb5a android@localhost #1 Wed Apr 15 17:28:55 CST 2015, EMU version: EMUI 3.0.

When I try to update the system I get this message "No updates", but the official website has the updates but it does not compatible with the device.

Comment: So your device is not eligible for the update. Note: flashing wrong files may brick your phone with no chance of recovery.

Comment: But the official website has the update for Huawei HONOR 4C but I can't find compatible update with the Build number CHM-U01 V100R001C185B067.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Honor 4C downloads on CarbonTesla's [Huawei Honor 4C Firmware & OTA](http://www.carbontesla.com/firmware-ota-section/huawei-firmware-ota-collection/huawei-honor-4c-firmware-ota/) page; according to your build number (C185B067) your device seems to be pakistan or Middle-East region. Follow up the link to the corresponding download section there, where you will find the files to download and a short instruction on how to proceed. According to that page, the firmware offered is Android 6.0 Marshmallow with EMUI v4.0, for the CHM-U01 as specified by you.

good luck..........